# LibreOffice Calc - How to reuse multi step formula?

Tags: formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, tax

I'm making a balance sheet, Sheet1 is for the ins and outs, and most values are added manually or simple formulas, and Sheet2 is where I created a formula, in the hopes of being able to reuse it.

I'm not an accountant to understand how I could make the calculations easier, and I'm a programmer, so I understand that the way I may be imagining the solution is likely impossible with the way Libreoffice Calc's formulas work.

So, to explain a bit.

On Sheet1, each column is a month, and the value is a tax that will appear one time each month, dependent on another value.

So, the base value is on ROW 17, **and on 18, I would like that result to be set. For every month, of course**

On Sheet2, I have the function, it contains 5 steps, with the values being reused a lot (hence, simplifying everything into one line would be hell).
[image: This is the complex formula in question, D1 is the input, C6 is the output.]

This is the complex formula in question, D1 is the input, C6 is the output.

The formula below is the one used on C2, and repeated down to C5.

I would like to keep the constants as a table since it would be easier to update it in the future in case it suffer any changes.

I have been searching for a possible solution but found none, and I believe that it's likely because I'm looking for a solution like a programmer (use Sheet as a function), and I should seek sort of way, but I don't know how Calc works.

In regards to the calculation, I don't know the specific name, but the idea is, from 0 to A1, I have to B1% from A1-0, then from A2-A1, remove B2%, and so on.

Of course the formula's complexity comes from treating lower values, so for example, if D1 was 2K, then I would have to take 7.5% of R$ 96.02, and everything beyond is 0, since there is nothing remaining for them to calculate

Answer (score 1):

Most of the descriptions I found on MULTIPLE.OPERATIONS were confusing, but I found one that made it much easier to understand.

The answer was to use this formula on `Sheet1`:

```
=MULTIPLE.OPERATIONS('Sheet2'.$C$6, 'Sheet2'.$D$1, C17)
```

I can just copy paste it to the side and the calculation will be executed properly.

To explain the arguments:

1 - where the result will appear

2 - the location of the main/first formula variable

3 - the location of dynamic variable you want to insert in that formula (So this is from Sheet1)

More arguments could be used if more variables were needed, but I just needed one.

This is the place with the best explanation I found for the function.

https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/MULTIPLE.OPERATIONS